# cut twice in field

Tags: awk, sed, logs, cut

I have a record like

```
192.168.28.168  user82  [08/May/2010:09:52:52]  "GET /NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1"     "http://www.example.com/index.html"     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 GTB7.0"
```

I want the final out put be like display only

```
   /NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1
```

I use this command and can get the following

```
cut -f4 example.log

"GET /NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1"
```

but, I need to remove ["GET] as well, how can I do that with cut or awk or sed?

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk '{ sub(/"/, "", $6); print $5, $6 }' file
```

The output:

```
/NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Sed`** approach:

```
sed -n 's/.*"GET \([^ ]* HTTP\/[0-9\.]*\)".*/\1/p' example.log
```

It searches for `*"GET (<no-whitespaces> HTTP/<digits-and-dots>)"*` and returns matches inside round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach with `gnu grep` and Perl regexps:

```
$ echo "$a"
192.168.28.168  user82  [08/May/2010:09:52:52]  "GET /NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1"     "http://www.example.com/index.html"     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 GTB7.0"

$ echo "$a" |grep -Po '(?<=GET ).*(?=".*"http)'
/NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1
$#or
$ echo "$a" |grep -Po '(?<=GET).*(?=".*"http)'
 /NoAuth/js/titlebox-state.js HTTP/1.1 #leading space preserved
```

`(?<=GET )`    == lookbehind for word `GET` & `space`
`.*`           == match any char zero or more times after lookbehind and till lookahead
`(?=".*"http)` == lookahead for `"` & `any char zero or more times` & `"http`